# Wrong promise.all() usage between functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I made this dummy code to have a better understanding on how promises work, mimicking a more complex software that I have to "promisify".
In the attached code, I wanted the events to fire and be logged in the following order:

- the "before" string
- the list of "... detected"
- the list of "done with ..."
- the "after" string

But as you can see if you run it, the "after" string is printed between steps 2 and 3.
Clearly, I must be doing something wrong in handling async logic.
Thanks for your help!

```js
const obj = {
  "rows": [{
    "type": "A",
    "value": 0
  }, {
    "type": "B",
    "value": 0
  }, {
    "type": "C",
    "value": 0
  }]
}
let promises = [];

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const alter_value = async(row, to_add, time) => {
  await delay(time);
  row.value = row.value + to_add;
  console.log("done with " + row.type);
  return true;
}

const two = async() => {
  obj.rows.forEach(async(row) => {
    switch (row.type) {
      case "A":
        console.log("A detected");
        promises.push(alter_value(row, 1, 1000))
        promises.push(alter_value(row, 2, 1800))
        break;
      case "B":
        console.log("B detected");
        promises.push(alter_value(row, 5, 1400))
        break;
      case "C":
        console.log("C detected");
        promises.push(alter_value(row, 200, 2400))
        break;
    }
  });

  return promises;
}

const one = async() => {
  console.log("before");
  Promise.all(two()).then(console.log("after"));
}

one();
```

Comment: `const jsonArray = { ... }` - That's not an array nor a JSON array. That's just a plain-old object.

Comment: you're right @ Andreas, I have corrected its name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two issues with your code, explaining the result you're getting:

1. Your `two` function should not be `async`. `async` functions return an implicit `Promise`. Here you just want to return an array of `Promise`s that you already construct yourself, so a normal function is what you need.
2. `.then(console.log("after"))` will execute the `console.log` right away: [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) expects a function to execute later, so you have to change it to `.then(() => console.log("after"))`.

This becomes:

```js
const obj = {
  "rows": [{
    "type": "A",
    "value": 0
  }, {
    "type": "B",
    "value": 0
  }, {
    "type": "C",
    "value": 0
  }]
};

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const alter_value = async (row, to_add, time) => {
  await delay(time);
  row.value = row.value + to_add;
  console.log("done with " + row.type);
  return true;
};

const two = () => {
  const promises = [];
  
  obj.rows.forEach(async(row) => {
    switch (row.type) {
      case "A":
        console.log("A detected");
        promises.push(alter_value(row, 1, 1000));
        promises.push(alter_value(row, 2, 1800));
        break;
      case "B":
        console.log("B detected");
        promises.push(alter_value(row, 5, 1400));
        break;
      case "C":
        console.log("C detected");
        promises.push(alter_value(row, 200, 2400));
        break;
    }
  });

  return promises;
};

const one = async () => {
  console.log('before');
  Promise.all(two()).then(() => console.log('after'));
};

one();
```

Note that, as an alternative to `.then()`, you can simply use `await` on `Promise.all` as well, to make your code more consistent:

```
await Promise.all(two());
console.log('after');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the OP requests synchronous behavior.

**Demo Outline**

- function `modVal(i, value, time)` parameters are derived from the async function `syncro()` parameter: `const sync` an array of objects. Each object contains the index of `obj.rows`, the value at that index `obj.rows[i].value`, and the time for the timeout in the Promise of `modVal()`.
- **Parameters and Arguments:** `const sync = [{r: 0, v: 1, t: 1000}, ...];`
  **seq.r:** `obj.rows[`**number**`]`
  **seq.v:** `obj.rows[seq.r].value +=` **number**
  **seq.t:** `...resolve(obj.rows[i].value += value),` **number**);
- `sync` array is iterated by a `for...of` loop. On each iteration `await modVal()` is called synchronously.

```js
let obj = {
  "rows": [{
    "type": "A",
    "value": 0
  }, {
    "type": "B",
    "value": 0
  }, {
    "type": "C",
    "value": 0
  }]
}

const sync = [{
  r: 0,
  v: 1,
  t: 1000
}, {
  r: 0,
  v: 2,
  t: 1800
}, {
  r: 1,
  v: 5,
  t: 1400
}, {
  r: 2,
  v: 200,
  t: 2400
}];

const syncro = async(sync) => {
  const modVal = (i, value, time) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(obj.rows[i].value += value), time);
    });
  }

  for (let seq of sync) {
    await modVal(seq.r, seq.v, seq.t);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.rows));
  }
}

syncro(sync);
```

```css
.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content:'';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  width:0;
}
```